# ¿Como almacenar números ingresados a un arreglo de manera continua?

Tags: php, array

El programa debe leer un valor detectar si es par; y si lo es, almacenarlo en un array y luego volver a preguntar hasta que el indice del array este completo.

El programa pregunta el tamaño del array; Luego imprime en un ciclo for, la cantidad de cajas de texto especificado en el indice. el problema esta que al enviarlo al segundo (array_key_exist) solo ingresa el utlimo valor de las cajas de texto.

¿Como almaceno el número ingresado por cada iteración?

```
<?php
        if(array_key_exists('enviar', $_POST))
        {
              $num = $_POST['num'];
              $num = $num-1;
              print"<p>Por favor, Ingrese solo números pares:</p>";

              for ($i=0; $i<=$num; $i++)
              {
                  print"<form action='lab44.php' method='POST'>";
                  echo"<br/>";
                  print"<input type='text' name= 'num2' value=''>";
                  echo"<br/>";
              }
              echo"<br/>";
              print"<input type='submit' name='enviar2' value='Enviar'>";
              print"</form>";
        }

        elseif (array_key_exists('enviar2', $_POST))
        {

        $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
        if(($num2%2)==0x|)
        {
            $arreglo[] = $num2;
            echo"<pre>";
            print_r($arreglo);
            echo"</pre>";
            echo"<br/>";
        }
        else
            {
            echo "El número ingresado anteriorente no es un número Par";
            /*echo "<br><br>";
            print"<form action='lab44.php' method='POST'>";
            print"<p>Por favor, Ingrese solo números pares:</p>";
            print"<input type='text' name='num2' value=''>";
            print"<input type='submit' name='enviar2' value='Enviar'>";
            print"</form>";*/
            }
        }

      else
      {
  ?>
    <form action="lab44.php" method="POST">
        <p>Por favor, Introduzca el indice del arreglo:</p>
        <input type="text" name="num" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>
   <?php
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: La cuestión es que cada vez que manda el formulario el ejecuta el script php una vez y ya está, y es solamente por ese momento, sí lo vuelves a enviar pues hace lo mismo con el valor que le envias, él no almacena ni deja guardados los datos que hayas enviado antes, a no ser que se lo indiques

Comment: Creo que hay varias formas de hacerlo, pero sí lo quieres hacer solo con php, podrías utilizar `$_SESSION[]`

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo esta solución:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['n_cajas']))
    $txt='
        <form>
        <input name="n_cajas"/> Número de cajas (tamaño del array)
        <button>Enviar</button>
        </form>
    ';
else{
    $txt='<form action="?n_cajas='.$_GET['n_cajas'];
    $txt.='" method="post">';
    for($i=0;$i<$_GET['n_cajas'];$i++){
        $txt.='<div>';
        $txt.='<input name="caja[]"';
        if(isset($_POST['caja'][$i])
            and is_numeric($_POST['caja'][$i])
            and $_POST['caja'][$i]%2==0)
                $txt.=' value="'.$_POST['caja'][$i].'"';
        $txt.='/>';
        $txt.='</div>';
    }
    $txt.='<button>Enviar</button>';
    $txt.='</form>';
}
echo $txt;
```

De un intento a otro voy almacenando los datos en el array `$_POST` del mismo formulario pero quedándome únicamente con los pares. Espero que sea lo que estabas buscando. Será un placer ampliar la respuesta con cualquier detalle que no veas claro. Por favor, indícamelo en los comentarios.